# Possible to pass an expression to a limit in BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

Is there any workaround to accomplish something like the following in BigQuery:

```
select 1 limit (select 1)
select 1 limit 2-1
```

In other words, pass an expression to the `LIMIT` keyword? Or, is there no possible way to emulate that behavior?

Comment: use dynamic sql https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/scripting?hl=de

Comment: @nbk can you show an example with the `(select 1)` example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Folowing the link provided, you can build it like this

```
DECLARE lim DEFAULT (SELECT 1);

EXECUTE IMMEDIATE """
 select 1 LIMIT ?
"""
USING  lim;
```

Answer (score 1):

> Or, is there no possible way to emulate that behavior?

I would rather go with below approach

```
select * 
from your_table 
qualify row_number() over() < (select 15 - 2)
```

or in more practical case  - something like

```
select * 
from your_table 
qualify row_number() over() < (select limit_value from other_table limit 1 )
```

Comment: could you please explain that technique a bit -- for example what does the `row_number() over()` do? Seems very neat!

Comment: sure. `row_number() over()` just literally assigns incremental numbers to each and every row in a table and then this number is used to limit output. if you need specific order - you can use `row_number() over(order by col)`. and finally if you need to limit output per each partition - you use `row_number() over(partition by col1 order by col2)`. hope this makes sense